# куки в javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
(function() {
  const wheel = document.querySelector('.wheel');
  const startButton = document.querySelector('.btn1');
  var deg = 0;
  const input = document.querySelector('#popup-callback-phone');
  const inputnames = document.querySelector('#consumers-feedback-names');

  startButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (input.checkValidity() & inputnames.checkValidity()) {
      startButton.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
      deg = 1000 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
      if (deg >= 181 && deg <= 225) {
        deg = 229;
      }
      wheel.style.transition = 'all 10s ease-out';
      wheel.style.transform = `rotate(${deg}deg)`;
      wheel.classList.add('blur');
    };
  });


  wheel.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
    wheel.classList.remove('blur');
    startButton.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
    wheel.style.transition = 'none';
    var actualDeg = deg % 360;
    wheel.style.transform = `rotate(${actualDeg}deg)`;
    var gifts;

    if (actualDeg >= 0 && actualDeg <= 45) {
      gifts = '1';
    } else if (actualDeg >= 45 && actualDeg <= 90) {
      gifts = '2';
    } else if (actualDeg >= 90 && actualDeg <= 135) {
      gifts = '3';
    } else if (actualDeg >= 135 && actualDeg <= 180) {
      gifts = '4';
    } else if (actualDeg >= 181 && actualDeg <= 225) {
      gifts = '5';
    } else if (actualDeg >= 225 && actualDeg <= 270) {
      gifts = '6';
    } else if (actualDeg >= 270 && actualDeg <= 315) {
      gifts = '7';
    } else if (actualDeg >= 315 && actualDeg < 360) {
      gifts = '8';
    } else {
      alert('net podarka');
    }
    $.fancybox.open($("#popup-success8"));
    document.getElementById("gifts").innerHTML = gifts;
  });
})();

$.fancybox.open({
  src: "#popup-callbac",
  hash: "popup-callbac",
  afterClose: function afterClose() {
    $("#popup-calc-result .popup__in .main-calc-list").remove();
  }
});
```

это колесо которое появляется в модальном окне, как сделать куки на 30 дней что бы пользовать смог сыграть только один раз в 30 дней ?

Comment: В месте, где человек уже покрутил колесо и выиграл что-то установить что-то вроде `document.cookie = "played=true";max-age="3600*24*30"`

Comment: к сожалению не работает

Comment: чтобы пользовать смог сыграть только один раз в 30 дней, нужно делать не посредством cookie.

Comment: 225 - это 4 или 5? =)

Comment: поправил ) только это сообщение о подарке )

Comment: а посредствам чего ?

Comment: Клиент работает только когда сайт открыт у пользователя, это нужно делать на стороне сервера.

Comment: мне просто нужно что бы пользователь который покрутил колесо при повторном заходе попап у него не открывался